Error in x[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
I am working on the Chapter 5.2 example in the book: https://otexts.com/fpp3/simple-methods.html, getting errors when testing the code that the instructor is using:
  filter(!is.na(Bricks)) %>%
  model(
    Seasonal_naive = SNAIVE(Bricks),
    Naive = NAIVE(Bricks),
    Drift = RW(Bricks - drift()),
    Mean = MEAN(Bricks)
  ) ```

Here below is an extract of the error message from RStudio whenever I run the code:

> Error in x[[1]] : subscript out of bounds


- should be ~ in RW(Bricks ~ drift()).
library(fpp3)

bricks <- aus_production |>
  filter_index("1970 Q1" ~ "2004 Q4") |>
  select(Bricks)

bricks |> 
  filter(!is.na(Bricks)) |> 
  model(
    Seasonal_naive = SNAIVE(Bricks),
    Naive = NAIVE(Bricks),
    Drift = RW(Bricks ~ drift()),
    Mean = MEAN(Bricks)
  )
#> # A mable: 1 x 4
#>   Seasonal_naive   Naive         Drift    Mean
#>          <model> <model>       <model> <model>
#> 1       <SNAIVE> <NAIVE> <RW w/ drift>  <MEAN>

Created on 2024-04-13 with reprex v2.1.0
